# Typesafe activator available command line options/features

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator, typesafe

Is there a way to find out all the possible activator command line options?

The `activator -help` only provides a bare minimum available option/feature list but all the nice things are hidden and not available even on the typesafe website online documentation.

So far I know of the following commands/features:

```
activator run
activator -jvm-debug 9999 run
activator compile
activator clean
activator clean compile dist
activator doc //creates a nice documentation of your whole project
```

Any idea where this is information is available?

('m using activator to run Play framework projects)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Activator* is not some tool that have some wide options. It looks like, but it is just a wrapper to run *sbt* project. From the activator source page in git:

> Activator aims to be a friendly one-stop-shop to bootstrap your Scala,
>   Akka, and Play development. It can be used as a wrapper script that
>   launches into traditional command line sbt, but it also includes a
>   template and tutorial system, and an optional GUI for getting started.
>
> You can think of Activator as traditional sbt (activator shell or
>   activator ), plus an optional UI mode (activator
>   ui), plus a template system (activator new).

That's all. Actually only four commands:

- *ui* - to run ui mode
- *new* - to create new project from the template
- *list-templates* - to show all available templates
- *shell* - to run sbt shell

Let's look in to this in a details.

The source code

https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/blob/master/launcher/src/main/scala/activator/ActivatorLauncher.scala

```
try configuration.arguments match {
  case Array("ui") => RebootToUI(configuration, version = checkForUpdatedVersion.getOrElse(APP_VERSION))
  case Array("new", _*) => Exit(ActivatorCli(configuration))
  case Array("list-templates") => Exit(TemplateHandler())
  case Array("shell") => RebootToSbt(configuration, useArguments = false)
  case _ if Sbt.looksLikeAProject(new File(".")) => RebootToSbt(configuration, useArguments = true)
  case _ => displayHelp(configuration)
} catch {
  case e: Exception => generateErrorReport(e)
}
```

You can see that there is only 4 commands *ui*, *new*, *list-template*, *shell* and one meta command:

```
case _ if Sbt.looksLikeAProject(new File(".")) => RebootToSbt(configuration, useArguments = true)
```

It means that if you run `activator` command in the project directory (and it's not `ui`, `new`, `list-template`, `shell`) than activator will run sbt with the command and argument that you pass to the activator. So `run`, `compile`, `stage` is not activator commands but sbt commands.

If you will run activator not in the project directory (and it's not `ui`, `new`, `list-template`, `shell` commands), then it will show you some "help page"

Activator also allow to pass java arguments that would be used for run activator.jar - you can see it by inspecting "activator.bat" file or activator shell script.

**SBT**

Reference of sbt commands you can found here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a complete list of activator command options either. Activator itself is not entirely open-sourced and the official document doesn't give much information.

But just to give you a different angle, activator was built based on sbt. So command options of sbt should also be valid in activator. See: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html.

As you will see, some of activator command options come directly from sbt.
Other than that, activator also has some customized options like `-jvm-debug` and `dist` as you list in your question.

Hope this is helpful to you.